# how to unlock edition of pom.xml in tab "Effective POM" on eclipse mars 4.5.0

Tags: eclipse, maven

I want to modify the content of pom.xml, but i cant edit it in "Effective POM" tab , eclipse mars 4.5.0

> I try to edit it as common files but no change on keydown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't modify it in effective-pom tab, that is read only tab, switch to `pom.xml` tab and edit it

Comment: yes i saw it, effective-pom tab content just a generated content after build action. thanks a lot!